# How to acess keys located in dictionary inside dictionar

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

for example please see below code :

```
{0.1: {'batsman': 'SC Ganguly', 'bowler': 'P Kumar', 'runs': \
      {'batsman': 0, 'total': 1, 'extras': 1}, \
      'extras': {'legbyes': 1}, \
      'non_striker': 'BB McCullum'}}
```

I want to acess the runs and keys inside the dictionary - how to acess it.

This actually acessing values which are located in dictionary inside dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain dictionary key indexers for nested dictionaries. Here is an example:

```
d[0.1]['runs']
```

Output:

```
{'batsman': 0, 'extras': 1, 'total': 1}
```

I have defined your dictionary as `d`, as follows:

```
d = {0.1: {'batsman': 'SC Ganguly', 'bowler': 'P Kumar', 'runs': \
          {'batsman': 0, 'total': 1, 'extras': 1}, \
          'extras': {'legbyes': 1}, \
          'non_striker': 'BB McCullum'}}
```

Comment: what is 'd' can u explain